# Domain redirecting to unusual port

Tags: router, ip, port-forwarding, hosting, web-hosting

I have a shared internet connection with other people. I want to host a website in my server that is connected to my router that is connected to the main router (which is shared between me and my neighbours). One of them also hosts a website in his server (connected to his router, connected to the main router). As he hosts his website longer than me, the router fowards the default HTTP and HTTPS to his website. Is there any way we can both have our websites int the same connection? I would host it in a different port but I didn´t want the website to be mydomain.me:5000 (if I hosted the website in the port 5000). Is there any way to do this? Have a domain (examplea.com) point to a website in one port and other domain (exampleb.com) point to other website in another port of the router being both in the same IP? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: The only solution for your case - is to use different port or bribe person who manage "main" router, so he will forward port 80/443 to your router instead of other, who running now web site on those ports

Comment: I also posted this question on other forums. They suggested me virtual host and host headers. I will explore both options.

Comment: If you have no control over "main" router, you can do whatever you want, but it won't force "main" router to forward ports 80/443 to another IP.